# Connection Pool - OkHttp

Tags: java, okhttp

We are using OkHttp in WAS environment Could you please help us with the below queries -:

- **Question 1:** What should be the ideal connection pool size and keep Alive for a container environment , is there any formula to calculate it, we will be using Okhttp client to connect to two different URL's
- **Question 2:** We don't want to have any client side failures , how does OkHttp handle stale connections , I don't see any parameter in OkHttp to check for stale connections?

HTTP Java client Java has this parameter to turn on stale connection check:

```
http.connection.stalecheck
```

We are using OkHttp client as mentioned below , is there any important configuration am I missing?

```
new OkHttpClient.Builder()
              .readTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
              .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
              .connectTimeOut(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
              .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(10,5,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
              .build();
```

Comment: ConnectionPool defined here is to configure only maxIdleConnections.
In your case you cocnfigured 10 maxIdleconnections with 5secs keepalive which is very less. There is no formula which tells you the right number you need to experiment based on your usecase

If you want to configure maxConnections for connectionpool use OkHttpClient.Builder.dispatcher(new Executors.newFixedThreadPool(<SIZE>))

Comment: We are using execute(sync)  as per OkHttp docs dispatcher will work if we use async

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What should be the ideal connection pool size and keep Alive for a container environment

*Take 256 as a starting point.* It's big enough that you'll get a good hit rate and small enough that you won't notice the memory used.

If you hit lots of different hosts frequently you may adjust it up. If you are running on very small containers or have memory sensitivity you may adjust it down.

> We dont want to have any client side failures

There's a setting on OkHttpClient.Builder, [retryOnConnectionFailure](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/-builder/retry-on-connection-failure/). It's true by default and will handle client-side failures for you. If you did want to handle client-side failures you'd set this to false.

Comment: thanks can you please help us Keep Alive also and also reg retryOnConnectionFailure how many times will it retry ? am using 4.7.2 version of Okhttp

Comment: It'll retry once per broken connection; typically that's at most once but in a contrived situation it could be multiple. OkHttp has a hard limit of 20 attempts also, which mostly applies to auth challenges and redirects.

Comment: can we go -ahead with default 5 minutes of Keep Alive ?

Comment: Yes. Anything between 5 seconds and 10 minutes should work.