# Efficient OkHttp configuration for Multithreaded environment

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, okhttp

What is the best configuration I can use to set up the OkHttp3 client correctly in a multi threaded environment? Had 2 main questions:

1. Connection pool - How do we define the number of available connections in the pool? Can it be scaled at runtime? The number of concurrent users will be very high and need to make sure users aren't waiting a long time for the connection to be available from the pool.
2. I read the OkHttp might end up doing multiple retries in case of failures or timeouts. Is it possible to only enable this for only the "Gets" and not "Post" while using just 1 OkHttp client?

Also Anything else I should be considering?

Here is my starting code for the client.

```
    private static final int timeout = 15000;
    private static final OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient()
            .newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .readTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
            .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC))
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the connection pool then pass into the client builder.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ConnectionPool.html

See [Connection Pool - OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63047533/connection-pool-okhttp) for an example.

For the second question, you can disable automatic retries and do this in your application code instead. Use `retryOnConnectionFailure(false)` as you show above.

To have this applied differently for get and posts you should use customise one client like the following

```
  val postClient = client.newBuilder().retryOnConnectionFailure(false).build()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. regarding question#1. I see the setting to set the max idle time but nothing regarding max connection in the pool. Just for my understanding.. lets say I go with the default of 5 max idle connections, and there are 7 concurrent API request, would this mean OkHttp will reuse the 5 idle connections in the pool and create additional 2 to handle the remaining requests? What would happen after the calls are complete.. would OkHttp just update the pooled connections and close the oldest 2 out of the 7 connections after?

Comment: regarding question#2 Is there a way to have it so that it does the retry for Get requests only and not other HTTP requests (http post for example)? What is the proper way to configure within the same client, if possible?

Comment: Added an option for get and post above.

Comment: If you have a client with high concurrency and HTTP/2, you might not find OkHttp works optimally with a single client.  It will reuse a single connection for multiple requests.  In that case creating a fixed number of clients with distinct connection pools might be optimal.